# Destructing Iterator.product in Julia

Tags: numpy, julia

I wonder if I have `Iterator.product` generating pairs `(x,y)` how I get only x-componnet out of it?

I'm trying to convert from `Python/numpy` to `julia` using this [cheatsheet](https://cheatsheets.quantecon.org/). Simple thing:

```
xs = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.1)
ys = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.1)
Xs,Ys = np.meshgrid(xs,ys)
F = sin(Xs)*cos(Ys)
```

Now in Julia I got I should use `Iterator.product`

```
xs = 0.0 : 0.1 : 2*pi
ys = 0.0 : 0.1 : 2*pi
XYs = Iterators.product(xs,ys)
for (i, (x,y)) in enumerate( XYs ) println("$i $x $y") end
# as far as good

# Now what?
 (Xs,Ys)=XYs ;  println(Xs); println(Ys)  # Nope
.(Xs,Ys)=XYs ; println(Xs); println(Ys)   # syntax: invalid identifier name "."    
Xs=xy[:,0]  ;  println(Xs)                # MethodError: no method matching getindex( ... 
XYs_T = transpose(XYs) ; println(XYs_T)   # MethodError: no method matching transpose( 

# this seems to work, but how to address index which is not "first" or "last" ?
Xs = first.(XYs)
Ys = last.(XYs)

# I guess I know how to continue
F = sin.(Xs)*cos.(Ys)

imshow(F)    # yes, corrent
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using the routines in Iterators if you use a comprehension:

```
julia> F = [sin(x) * cos(y) for x in xs, y in ys]
63×63 Array{Float64,2}:
  0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0        …   0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
  0.0998334   0.0993347   0.0978434   0.0953745   0.0919527      0.0925933   0.0958571   0.098163    0.0994882
  0.198669    0.197677    0.194709    0.189796    0.182987       0.184262    0.190756    0.195345    0.197982
  0.29552     0.294044    0.289629    0.282321    0.272192       0.274089    0.28375     0.290576    0.294498
...
```

Remember that since Julia organizes arrays in memory by column first and Python row first, if you want the arrays to display the same in the REPL, you will need to reverse the order of x and y in the array reference, as in the 'ij' matrix indexing option of numpy's meshgrid:

```
F = [sin(x) * cos(y) for y in ys, x in xs] # BUT reference elements as e = F[y, x] now
```

Comment: thanks, good to know, but still would be nice how to decompose such *compoud* iterator xy above iterator to components. When there is `first` and `last` there must be also something like normal index.

Comment: You could use a comprehension again: Xs = [x for (x,y) in XYs]; Ys = [y for (x, y) in XYs];

Answer (score 2):

You can use comprehensions, but I like broadcasting:

```
xs = range(0, 2π, step=0.1)
ys = range(0, 2π, step=0.1)
F = sin.(xs) .* cos.(ys')  # notice the adjoint '
```

You should avoid creating the intermediate meshgrid, that's just wasted. In fact, you should go read the manual section on broadcasting: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1

The same thing applies in Python, btw, there is no need for `meshgrid`, just make sure that `xs` is a row vector and `ys` a column vector (or vice versa), then you can directly multiply `np.sin(xs) * np.cos(ys)`, and they will broadcast to matrix form automatically.

Comment: thanks, this way is perhaps better ... but anyway ... if there are functions like `zip` there must be also inverse functions aka `unzip` ? No?

Comment: I've heard multiple times that `zip` is its own inverse, but I'm not sure how that works. But if you just want the first component of each pair, try `first.(p)` where `p` is a collection or iterator of tuples/pairs. For the last component, use `last.(p)`, and for more general indices, `getindex.(p, n)`.

Comment: the problem is, this works fine: `Xs = first.(XYs)`, this does not work: `Xs = getindex.(XYs, 0)`

Comment: You cannot get index 0. The first element has index 1.

Comment: aha ... :) ( I like counting from zero more, but fine). And if getindex is the function connected to `[ ]` operator, cannot I do something like `XYs.[1]` ?

Comment: It has been discussed, but no, not currently.